# Function to evaluate exponent

Tags: c

I wrote the following code in c to evaluate exponent of a number without using the math library

```
#include <stdio.h>

float powr(float,int);

int main(){
    float a;
    int b;
    printf("Enter base and exponent a^b: ");
    scanf("%.2f %d",&a,&b);
    float p=powr(a,b);
    printf("%.2f",p);
    return 0;
}

float powr(float x,int y){
    float r=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=y;i++){
        r=r*x;
    }
    return(r);
}
```

but no matter what base and exponent I input, the ouput always comes out to be 1.00. I can't find any mistake in this program and I tried running the powr function algorithm inside main() in a seperate program and it works.

Comment: Please enable warnings in your compiler and fix them. They are usually there for a good reason: https://godbolt.org/z/vhGGqWrv7

Comment: Ignoring the return value of scanf is a mistake 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `scanf()` it onlys accepts field-width format, but no precision, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

You can just input the value, like this:

```c
scanf("%f %d",&a,&b);
```

Also, you should always check the return value of `scanf()`. Something like this:

```
numOfItems = scanf("%.2f %d",&a,&b);
if(numOfItems != 2) // uh-oh
{
    printf("Error while input!");
}
```